# Python Mock two functions in Pytest test using MagicMock

Tags: python-3.x, testing, mocking, pytest, magicmock

This is the function I am trying to test.

```
def service_request(url, session=configure_session()):
    response = session.get(url)

    document = json.loads(response.text)
    return document
```

Yes it is basic right now (hardly worth testing you might argue), but if I can get the mocking working I will be able to add more logic to it and test the new additions as I go. I have tried various things to mock two other functions called within this test. One is the `configure_session` function and the other is the `get` method from the `requests` library.

The `configure_session` function builds the `requests.Session` object configured with certificates required to make a request to the service. This method also optionally verifies the SSL connection with the CA bundle. The `config` file, imported at the top of the file (not shown) retrieves environment variables and is working as expected.

```
def configure_session():
    session = requests.Session()

    session.cert = (config.client_cert, config.client_key)
    if config.ssl_verify:
        session.verify = config.ca_bundle
    else:
        session.verify = False

    user_agent = f'{config.user_agent_version}'
    session.headers.update({'User-Agent': user_agent,
                     'Accept': 'application/json'})
    return session
```

This is the latest code I have tried. The `load_fixture` method is a test utility method and is working as expected.

```
def test_request():
    response_fixture = load_fixture('example_response.json')

    mock_session = MagicMock()
    mock_get = MagicMock()
    mock_session.get.return_value = mock_get
    mock_get.text.return_value = response_fixture

    test_url = "https://url-for-test/with/the/path/here"

    expected_headers = { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'test_user_agent_from_env_vars'
         }

    service_request(test_url, mock_session)

    mock_session.get.assert_called_with(
        test_url,
        headers=expected_headers
        )
    assert response == response_fixture
```

The current error is  `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'MagicMock'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in `document = json.loads(response.text)` when a MagicMock instance was being passed into `json.loads()`.

This is what fixed the problem.

```
mock_session = MagicMock()
mock_session.get.return_value.text = response_fixture
```